# Why does synchronized(this) works?

Tags: java

The "this" object is different for the two threads, since they are two different objects. So they are checking two different locks, so nothing should stop them from running in parallel a critical section :

```
void method() {
    synchronized(this) {
        //critical section
    }
}
```

What do I miss ?

Comment: You're missing a lot. The this statement refers the business object the thread has entered. It has nothing to do with the thread instances. The synchronized(this) allows no more than one thread at a time to enter that code block for that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example where it is the same object for two threads:

```
class Test {

    void method() {
        synchronized(this) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Test t1 = new Test();
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                t1.method();
            };
        }.start();
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                t1.method();
            };
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example made it clear, I thought the "this" was the Thread object as the article I was reading only provided a short block of code.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a critical section, it usually involves a single object. In these cases, if two different instances run in parallel, there are no race conditions, assuming they only work on instance-local resources, such as private fields.

What you might have missed is if objects of the same type work on a shared resource, synchronized(this) will indeed not block them from accessing it in parallel. In this case you can synchronize on the class itself using `synchronized(MyFoo.class) { }` or a shared variable.

Answer (score 0):

You do not miss anything. If both your threads try to apply `synchronized` and try to lock monitors of two different objects, they won't block each other.

Answer (score 0):

Every object in Java has a lock mechanism, and only one thread at a time can occupy the lock. When you surround a block of code with synchronize(this) or add a synchronize keyword to a method, it restricts only one thread to those synchronized areas for that object. It has nothing to do with thread instances, nor do two instances of the same class share a lock.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple threads of same Object are calling method(); then at a time only one thread will get object's monitor. but if there are different - different object of same type then they can enter parallel way.

the only problem in this code will happen when you are having any class variable, so that will be shared by all that time you have to use class Level lock.